# how to pass position of listview items to another listview adapter and set text of textview according to position

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

i have Two list-view activity.

In first list-view activity i have link to open second list-view activity. In Second list-view i have 5 rows. i want to pass the position of second list-view item to first first activity and according to position set text for only second row.

i can pass static data form second list-view activity to first list-view activity with finish(), but i don't know how to set it to selected row and i don't know how to pass position of second list-view with finish().

Anyone can help then please write code. for this

i want to set text for second row of first list-view.also write for this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize `startActivityForResult()` to launch the second activity. By calling that instead of `startActivity()` your first activity will be noticed when the second one completes.

In your `FirstActivity`, launch the second activity using this:

```
Intent launch2ndActivity = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(launch2ndActivity, 610);
```

Then on your `SecondActivity`:

```
// Do what do you need to do here. 
//I assume you would need to get the position of your ListView upon item click.
..
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent resultIntent = this.getIntent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("clicked_row", position);
        SecondActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

The last thing you'd need to do is specify how your `FirstActivity` should react upon recieving the result from `SecondActivity`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
    case 610:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle res = data.getExtras();
            int clickedRow = res.getInt("clicked_row");
            // Do what you want with that value..
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have used StartActivityForResult(). But how to pass position and how to set it in baseadapter for second row..?

Comment: its show error like this .  `this.getIntent() is undefine `

Comment: thank @ridsatrio, this is working. i have just remove `this.` and keep only `getintent();`